# Firefox, go to home page keyboard shortcut

Tags: macos, firefox, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook

On a Macbook Pro Keyboard, what is the keyboard shortcut for going to the home page in Firefox 3.5?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[These people](http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=605105) say it's <kbd>opt</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>left arrow</kbd>

Comment: How to make it work with bluetooth connected keyboard (https://www.logitech.com/en-us/product/mk850-wireless-keyboard-mouse-combo) in mac os high sierra, i never thought it would be so complicated to make it work :(

Answer (score 1):

It's Option-Home

Comment: There's no home button on the MBP keyboards

Comment: It's printed on mine ;-) Fn + Left Arrow = Home, so Option + Home would be Option + Fn + Left Arrow on my MacBook.

Answer (score 1):

<kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> on Windows and Linux. I think that's equivalent to <kbd>Option</kbd> + <kbd>Home</kbd> on a Mac.

Answer (score 0):

According to several sites, shortcuts are the same on OSX than on Windows, however you just substitute <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> for <kbd>Command</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd> for <kbd>Option</kbd>

OSX - <kbd>Option</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>

Windows - <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Home</kbd>

Comment: It's Alt + Home on Windows, Ctrl + Home just takes you to the top of the page :)

Comment: Thanks! +1 and edited... I don't mind being downvoted when I am actually wrong and people tell me!